# I've accidentally used browser-sync without going to the local folder

Tags: node.js, github, command-prompt, browser-sync

Am I in trouble?

I've very new to code and just learning how to update my repository or something on github.

Anyway, I went and tried to use browser-sync and used the following command:

```
browser-sync start -- server -- directory --files "*"
```

only for my firewall to prompt me about blocking some features of the program nodejs. Like it said from a video, a tab was made on chrome but instead of some specific folder, it showed ALL my folders in my local user like the the Documents, Pictures, Downloads etc. I think this was because I didn't cd to the specific folder I want to show

My pc is new so there really wasn't much in it but I'm scared I may have compromised my security. In panic, just exited both the firewall prompt and the tab so I wasn't able to snip it.

I don't know if I left some vital info out but that's just it. What should I do? I don't care much about my files but I've saved some of my passwords on chrome (social media sites, mostly. Few about my job. Nothing on payments) . Should I just change all of them? What are the steps I should do?

Comment: Hi I think you opened your main drive on a browser with browser-sync. As far that I can see is browser-sync is a local server that reloads the browser. The firewall prompt was to ask you if other computers on your network are allowed to access the local server.

So long you did not make a git repo on your main drive and pushed it. You will be alright with the files. I don't think you need to worry about your passwords saved in your browser since I think that browser-sync doen't have access to it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I was worried I might have to change my password on emails and everything.  Thanks a lot!